# Nested functions within a function in excel

Tags: nested

I am trying to create a worksheet that summarizes a chequeing account by amount,by account number and  date,  if the date is July(6), and place it in col G1
A                        B             C                           G       H
Account                   Date          Amount                     Account   Amount
06962-5001371             2023-06-10     10.00
06962-5001371             2023-06-10     11.00
06962-5001372             2023-06-10     12.00
06962-5001372             2023-06-10     14.00
06962-5001373             2023-06-10     15.00
06962-5001373             2023-06-10     16.00

=G1 =IF((MONTH(E1:E8)=6),IF(D1="06962"-5001371,SUM(F1:F8,0)))

Example returns All true but nothing in G1 or #SPILL if i change the Parameters

I have been wrecking my brains for weeks tries SUMPRODUCT but that only five me a totals for all all amounts.

Thanking you in advance if you can please relieve my agony on this one.

Norm

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.